Expression.Error: A cyclic reference was encountered during evaluation. Extract date
let
Source = Book,
// Step 1: Extract the date part (10 characters after the space)
ExtractedDate = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Extracted Date", each Text.Middle([Column1], Text.PositionOf([Column1], " ") + 1, 10)),

// Step 2: Convert the extracted text to a proper date type
ConvertedDate = Table.AddColumn(ExtractedDate, "Converted Date", each Date.FromText([Extracted Date])),

// Step 3: Format the date as DD-MM-YYYY
FormattedDate = Table.AddColumn(ConvertedDate, "Formatted Date", each Date.ToText([Converted Date], "dd-MM-yyyy"))

in
FormattedDate
"RandomFileName 2024-09-23t05_22_46.000000000" to a Column that Shows date like 23-09-2024

The coding you provided should work. Which step did you encounter the error?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
